# Preferred MultiThreading approach/library in VS 2010?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a lot of experience with multithreaded programming under Unix, PThreads and OpenMP.  My question to the community is this:  When writing a Windows app (XP, Win 7) and using VS 2010, is there a preferred or a best of library or multithread enabler ?

thanks for your opinions.

Comment: If you're already an experienced multithreaded developer, then the one that allows you to hit the ground running.  OpenMP is available on Windows, `boost::thread` is very similar to `pthreads`.

Comment: Windows Thread pool API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Parallel patterns Library (PPL), this is the latest library that has been designed by MS and is heavily optimised: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl25 it is supported natively in VS2010 I would prefer this to OpenMP certainly, there are also numerous msdn articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx, you also get the debugger with VS2010 and in ultimate you get a profiler, if you're a student then you get Ultimate for free anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Just learned this:  the new 2011 standard for C++ has official set of multithreading template which should make it fully transportable.